# How do you make a block comment in python?

Tags: python

I have tried using triple quotes but it only turns the code green. As if i were to print it. Not red

```
"""
How do i make a block comment
"""
```

So how can i make a block comment, or is it supposed to be green.

Comment: Yes. The answer is yes. I have no idea what green code means in your unspecified IDE or why you think that's an issue.

Comment: Python doesn't have multiline comments as such. There's nothing wrong with using multiline string literals as comments though.

Comment: @Rawing Yes it does, highlight the region and ALT + 3

Comment: @Wright Gives me a £ sign…

Answer (score 10):

```
'''
This is a multiline
comment. I can type here whatever I want.
'''
```

Comment: How is this different to what the OP is trying to do?

Comment: Well he used 4 quotes at the end, im just showing how proper block comments work :)

Answer (score 1):

You have too many quotes in the closing line - you have 4. It should be 3