# How can I add a comment block to a source file

Tags: python, file

i am working on a python script that needs to add this comment block to source files. I would like to insert the comment block (located below) at certain line offsets. For example, hypothetically speaking, if i needed to insert the comment block into a source file between lines 4 - 13, how would I do so? Even if those lines are already taken up, I essentially need it to overwrite them regardless. Is this possible?

```
//# [words]
//# [words]
//# [words]
//# [words]
//# [words]
//# [words]
//# [words]
//# [words]
//# [words]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make a block comment in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520811/how-do-you-make-a-block-comment-in-python)

Comment: If you want the resulting code to compile, you'll want `# [words]` instead of `//# [words]`.

Comment: Your question does not agree with itself.  You say that you want to "insert" the block, and you also say you want to "overwrite" the existing lines.  Which is it?

Comment: In general it's much easier to create a new file with whatever content you like and then rename it to the old filename, instead of actually modifying the existing file.